# Are charts inverses of parametrizations? In the definition of a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

Different books seem to define the "patches" of a smooth manifold differently.

One example is defining an $n-$ dimensional smooth manifold $M$ by **charts** which are homeomorphic maps $\phi_a : U_a \to R^n$ where $U_a$ are open sets in $M$ where the change of basis $\phi_b \circ \phi_a^{-1}$ to be smooth.

On the other hand, some books define injective maps $f_a: V_a \to M$ where $V_a$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $p \in M$ and $p \in f_a(V_a)$ to be a **parametrization**.

Are these maps inverses? Because $f_a$ is not necessarily continuous and not bijective. The vocabulary here just confuses me sometimes.

Comment: Yes, parametrizations are the inverses of charts. In your notation, $f_a$ is injective and therefore is a bijective between $V_a$ and $f(V_a)$. So, everything works fine.

Comment: @rdias Wait why is it surjective? I think once that is settled, we can take the map to map open sets into open sets since $f^{-1}f = I$

Comment: Every injective function $h:X\to Y$ is a bijection between $X$ and $h(X)$. It's obviously surjective over $h(X)$ and since it's injective, we have a one-to-one relation.

Comment: @rdias, oh with its *image* is a bijective function. And the cover $\{ f(V_a) \]$ covers $M$ justifying the continuity part.